# What's the difference between fetchRequestWithEntityName and initWithEntityName?

Tags: objective-c

While I realize one is a class method and the other an instance method, they have the exact same description in the Apple docs so I'm not quite understanding the different syntax/use cases.

Comment: You will be having a nice description about [Difference between fetchRequestWithEntityName and initWithEntityName](http://blog.csdn.net/nerohoop/article/details/7065982).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you said, if they really have the same use case, the only difference has to do with the garbage collection on objective-C, according to the memory management design Apple uses.

Whenever you call an `init` method over an object, you own it and you are responsible for releasing it when you no longer need the object.

When you call any other kind of method that returns an object, that object is added to a `NSAutoreleasePool`, and it is `autorelease`d when the pool gets drained.

You can get more insights [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-CJBEJBHH).

So, following Apple's way, if you don't want so save the object for further use, you can call `fetchRequestWithEntityName` and not worry about releasing the object at the end of the method call. If you want to save it as an instance variable, you call the `initWithEntityName` method . They can, of course be interchanged, but this approach follows apple guidelines in what comes to memory management.

```
-(void)myMethod {
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  id obj1 = [[Object alloc] initWithEntityName:...];
  id obj2 = [Object fetchRequestWithEntityName:...];

  //obj1 retain count is +1
  //obj2 retain count is +0 (likely autoreleased)

  [pool drain];

  //obj1 still exists
  //obj2 is no longer valid; may or may not have been deallocated 
}
```

So basically, `fetchRequestWithEntityName` is achieved by:

```
+(id)fetchRequestWithEntityName:... {
  return [[[self class] alloc] initWithEntityName:...] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: You can't assume anything about the absolute value of the retain count.   In fact, your original code was wrong in stating that "obj2 retainCount is 2"....   fixed.   For `obj2` to survive the `drain`, you would need to explicitly `retain` it before the drain, making it "+1".

Comment: Yes, in my first annotation I should've included `//assume obj1 retain count is 1` instead of inferring a retain count of 1, but your fix is more descriptive. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Their functionality is equivalent, but the class method returns an autoreleased object. That is, it's probably implemented along the lines of:

```
+ (NSFetchRequest *)fetchRequestWithEntityName:(NSString *)entityName {
    return [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:entityName] autorelease];
}
```

This is a fairly common pattern in Objective-C libraries known as [Class Factory methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW36).

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between those two API is as below:

`fetchRequestWithEntityName` will give you an autorelease object, so once the event loop is over  it will be deallocated from the memory until you retain it.

But `initWithEntityName` will give you object which is to be released by you otherwise there will be memory leak.